# How to do system polling call POLLRDHUP in Kubernetes for Postgres to do `client_connection_check_interval`?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes

I am running Postgres 15 from Percona Postgres Operator on Kubernetes, and unfortunately, there is a non-configurable load balancer that will close idle connections after 180s.

I have configured Postgres with `client_connection_check_interval`, but a `tcpdump` on the client side where i run `psql` shows no packet from Postgres check.

The connection is `psql` -> internet -> provider managed LB -> Traefik ingress -> Postgres . There is no Pgbouncer involved in this test

I was expecting Postgres to send some high level applicative check messages, but documentation says it relies on non-standard Linux extension `POLLHUP` or `POLLRDHUP`

*i tried also to play with parameters `tcp_keepalives...` on both psql and Postgres, but it did not seem to work either, probably because of all the TCP proxying involved aith the LB and Traefik*

Answer (score 0):

Even using `tcp_keepalives_idle` settings in Postgres is designed to send periodic keepalve packets to the client. it may not be effective showing packets from idle connections. You can consider using a LB with [pgbouncer](https://docs.percona.com/percona-operator-for-postgresql/2.0/expose.html#pgbouncer).

Comment: i did try with Pgbouncer. But it did not help, since Pgbouncer is also behing the impatient LB. I was expecting for Postgres to send more "high level" aka applicative keepalives though all the intermediaries to simulate traffic.